# Zend_Db_Table_Rowset: how to get table info (metadata) when using JOINS?

Tags: php, zend-framework, metadata, join

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get the metadata info from a Zend_Db_Table_Rowset class when using joins in the query that produced that result set?  It's easy when there are no joins involved.. for example:

```
foreach ($rowset as $row) {
    $info = $row->getTable()->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::METADATA);
    Zend_Debug::dump($info); // outputs array of column info including data type
}
```

But when I do that to a row that came from a query using joins I just get the data from the main table I was selecting from..

Answer (score 0):

Jose, what kind of metadada info do you need? Maybe there is an alternate way to achieve what you want. Since the joins are always done from one table (and you join it to others) I think you will always get the metadata info for the first one.

By any chance are you doing dynamic joins?

Comment: Well I actually have already achieved a work-around.  Instead of creating one $cols array and passing empty arrays to all the join() calls I've separated each table's columns into its own array and made getters for those arrays.  It's by far not a great solution but it works.  I want something that doesn't involve me hard coding a bunch of column data into arrays..  Dynamic joins you say?  How so?  I have a predefined amount of joins I'm doing if that's what you wanted to know..

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I guess you solved it then! By dynamic joins I meant having a table like the one below and having your joins be done agains whatever is in the table. So "table" could be the name of any table in the database and this row could be pointing to any row in any table. I've seen this in CMSs but have no idea how to use them in ZF! (that's why I was asking!)

CREATE TABLE `dynamicrows` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tableId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Oh I see. (Sorry about the _super late_ response). No I wasn't doing dynamic joins like that. Saludos

Comment: I accepted your answer as the solution is in my comment. Thanks for trying